# How to customize Menu tab (Ribbon/command bar) in Microsoft Dynamics CRM?

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I'm recently developing a CRM application using Microsoft Dynamics 365. How do we customize the menu tab in Microsoft CRM as shown in attached Figure? Please let me know the steps to do so. Please check snap here.

[image]

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309639.aspx

Comment: your question on google returns hundreds of useful links, tutorials i applications. Have you even tried to search for something?

Comment: @PawelGradecki Yes, I tried implementing lots of different solutions given, but somehow it ended up in giving me more errors. May be cause there is difference of version between what I'm using & what is given there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the [Ribbon Workbench from Develop1](https://www.develop1.net/public/rwb/ribbonworkbench.aspx).

The download is a managed CRM solution which you import into your CRM environment. The solution provides a great and intuitive interface for editing ribbon bars throughout your CRM organisation.