# Dynamics CRM 365 : Downloading a Word Document Template via a Button on the Ribbon

Tags: ms-word, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365, crm-ribbon-workbench, document-template

Currently users have to click the ellipses, word templates, and finally quote to download the word template.

[image: ellipses, word templates, and finally quote]

To make it easier for our users we would like to have the document download when pressing the "print quote" button on the ribbon.

[image: print quote]

Is this possible? If so how would I go about doing this? I understand how to edit the ribbon using the ribbon workbench. I need to know how to download a word template using the ribbon.
[image: ribbon workbench]

If the solution is using the ribbon workbench, what command can I enter to get the word template to download?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to customize Menu tab in Microsoft Dynamics CRM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44515209/how-to-customize-menu-tab-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm)

Comment: No it's not exact duplicate. Same ribbon/command bar customization but this is more genuine..

Comment: @JacobH This is not a duplicate. I know how to edit the ribbon. I need to know how I can download a word template using a button on the ribbon.  I have updated my question. See above ^.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
ExecuteWordMerge = function (wordtemplateid, entitytypecodeint, ids, templatetype, fieldforfilename, filenameoverride) {
        try {
            Xrm.Page.ui.clearFormNotification("worderror");
            var funcpath = Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/_grid/print/print_data.aspx";
            if (typeof ids !== "object") {
                var tids = ids;
                ids = new Array();
                ids.push(tids);
            }
            var wordTemplateId = wordtemplateid;//"f1f7b994-543b-e711-8106-c4346bac2908" test data;
            var currentEntityTypeCode = entitytypecodeint;//"10063" test data;
            var templateType = (templatetype || 9940); //9940 is global and 9941 is personal
            var fieldForFileName = (fieldforfilename || "");
            var formdata = "exportType=MergeWordTemplate&selectedRecords=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(ids)) +
            "&associatedentitytypecode=" + currentEntityTypeCode + "&TemplateId=" + wordTemplateId + "&TemplateType=" + templateType;
            var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            req.open("POST", funcpath, true);
            req.responseType = "arraybuffer";
            req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8");
            req.setRequestHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
            req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            req.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState == 4) {/* complete */
                    req.onreadystatechange = null;
                    if (this.status >= 200 && this.status <= 299) {//200 range okay
                        var mimetype = (2 === 2) ? "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" : "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                        var blob = new Blob([req.response], { type: mimetype });
                        var fileNameTemplate = req.getResponseHeader('content-disposition').split('filename=')[1].replace(/'/g, "");
                        var dloadurl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                        var filename = (fieldForFileName !== "" && Xrm.Page.getAttribute(fieldForFileName) !== null && Xrm.Page.getAttribute(fieldForFileName).getValue() !== "") ?
                            Xrm.Page.getAttribute(fieldForFileName).getValue() : fileNameTemplate;
                        filename = filenameoverride || filename;
                        //new code, prevent IE errors
                        if (navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
                            navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, filename);
                            return;
                        }
                        else if (window.navigator.msSaveBlob) { // for IE browser
                            window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
                            return;
                        }
                        var a = document.createElement("a");
                        document.body.appendChild(a);
                        a.style = "display: none";
                        a.href = dloadurl;
                        a.download = filename;
                        a.click();
                        URL.revokeObjectURL(dloadurl);
                        //window.location = dloadurl;//we can use just this instead of creating an anchor but we don't get to the name the file
                    }
                    else {
                        Xrm.Page.ui.setFormNotification("An Error occurred generating the word document, please contact support if the issue persists,code: " + this.status, "ERROR", "worderror");
                    }
                }
            };
            req.send(formdata);
        }
        catch (err) {
            Xrm.Page.ui.setFormNotification("An Error occurred generating the word document, please contact support if the issue persists. " + err.message, "ERROR", "worderror");
        }

    }
```

Comment: a.click(); On Internet explorer is throwing access denied error, but when running from Chrome, Filed is being downloaded but it says "The file is corrupt and cannot be opened". Any Idea how to deal with these 2 issues.

Comment: Also, in case it helps those of you who are working with CRM templates,  the wordtemplateid will change any time you have to make edits to a template, which is no good. So, I've made a CRM solution for that which you can download using the link below. The solution is simple and allows you to download and update existing templates so the ID doesn't need to change. http://teameasi.com/blog/365-document-template-downloader

Comment: AnkUser - I fixed the IE bug but on the Chrome issue I can't reproduce that.  Are you sure your word template isn't corrupt?  Can you execute it using the native Word Templates menu without issues?

Answer (score 4):

When you click the templates flyout, it's dynamically populated through an invocation of `/AppWebServices/DocumentTemplate.asmx`, which returns the XML for the menu.

The flyout for Word Templates in the Incident home page grid looks like this:

```
<Menu Id="incident|NoRelationship|HomePageGrid|Mscrm.HomepageGrid.incident.WordTemplates.Menu">
    <MenuSection Id="incident|NoRelationship|HomePageGrid|Mscrm.HomepageGrid.incident.WordTemplates.Menu.CreateTemplates" Title="Create Word Template" Sequence="10" DisplayMode="Menu16">
        <Controls Id="incident|NoRelationship|HomePageGrid|Mscrm.HomepageGrid.incident.WordTemplates.Menu.CreateTemplates.Controls">
            <Button Id="incident|NoRelationship|HomePageGrid|Mscrm.HomepageGrid.incident.WordTemplates.Menu.CreateTemplates.Controls.00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" Command="incident|NoRelationship|HomePageGrid|Mscrm.WordTemplate.CreateWordTemplate.Grid" Sequence="10" ToolTipDescription="Create Word Template" Alt="Create Word Template" LabelText="Create Word Template" />
        </Controls>
    </MenuSection>
    <MenuSection Id="incident|NoRelationship|HomePageGrid|Mscrm.HomepageGrid.incident.WordTemplates.Menu.WordTemplates" Title="Word Templates" Sequence="20" DisplayMode="Menu16">
        <Controls Id="incident|NoRelationship|HomePageGrid|Mscrm.HomepageGrid.incident.WordTemplates.Menu.WordTemplates.Controls">
            <Button Id="incident|NoRelationship|HomePageGrid|Mscrm.HomepageGrid.incident.WordTemplates.Menu.WordTemplates.Controls.9b77c5b0-1033-4741-a01c-afdbdb1c3f22" Command="incident|NoRelationship|HomePageGrid|Mscrm.WordTemplate.TemplatesMenu.Grid" Sequence="10" ToolTipDescription="Case Summary" Alt="Case Summary" LabelText="Case Summary" />
        </Controls>
    </MenuSection>
</Menu>
```

I don't have the means to try it out at the moment, but I'd try and "copy" the last `<Button>`:

```
<Button Id="incident|NoRelationship|HomePageGrid|Mscrm.HomepageGrid.incident.WordTemplates.Menu.WordTemplates.Controls.9b77c5b0-1033-4741-a01c-afdbdb1c3f22" Command="incident|NoRelationship|HomePageGrid|Mscrm.WordTemplate.TemplatesMenu.Grid" Sequence="10" ToolTipDescription="Case Summary" Alt="Case Summary" LabelText="Case Summary" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I am having the issue of when the button is added to the ribbon with the same id as the Quote item in the drop down neither of them work since only one of them can have the same id at a time.

<Button Id="Mscrm.Form.quote.WordTemplates.Menu.WordTemplates.Controls.4ab391a4-d247-e711-80d3-005056914ea2" Command="vsi.quote.Download.Command" Sequence="8" ToolTipDescription="Download Quote" Alt="Download Quote" LabelText="Download Quote" />

Comment: Id must always be unique, I'd simply make something up i.e. `Id="vsi.quote.Download.Button"`

Comment: Unfortunately, the id appears to be what causes the download since it has the id of the document template.  Remove the id and no download.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to do this using only supported features of CRM (of course I'm sure it's also possible to do using unsupported javascript, but I don't have time currently to investigate this). The steps that you should take to achieve the functionality you want:

1. Create new process of type Action, bound to entity that you want to
   create a template for (the reason why I suggest Action here, is that
   it can be easily invoked using JavaScript and CRM WebAPI)
2. In this Action add single step - invoke an Action and choose
   built-in action "SetWordTemplate"
3. Set Properties of this action - choose the template that you need
   and dynamically set the target to current entity (using Dynamic
   Values assistant) If you never used this action - it simply creates
   a given word template and adds it as an annotation to your entity
4. Now you need to write logic inside your button (I'm assuming you
   know how to add a button using Ribbon Workbench or whatever)
5. Call your action using WebAPI
6. Find annotation that was just created for your entity with the
   attached document
7. Download the attachment (you can show some prompt for the user or
   simply force the download the file, user will have to save it)
8. Delete the annotation

Maybe not a one-liner, but keeps you in the supported zone...

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Sorry for the late response I had another project I had to work on last week.  I am attempting your solution and so far I have made it to step 6.  The ribbon button saves the quote as a note.  However, the api returns a 204 No Content so I do not get the id of the new annotation.  How would you suggest I get the id of the newly created note so I can then call the web api to download the word doc and then delete?

Comment: @Pawel: Is it possible to download the doc attachment from CRM to local folder using c# lets say in console app ?

I am able to download the file which is attached manually in CRM but unable to download the doc which got attached by using "Document Generation" feauture

Answer (score 1):

Just to simplify @TeamEASI.com answer a little here is what I did.

1. Add a button to the ribbon using XRMToolBox Ribbon Workbench 2016.
   [image: add button to ribbon]
2. Create a JS web resource like the one bellow.

```js
/*
* Author:      Matthew Hunt
* File:        vsi_DownloadTemplate.js
* Date:        12/20/2017
* Project:     CRM USA
* Description: DownloadTemplate() allows the user to download a document template 
* via a button on the ribbon.
*
* @param entitytypecode: the type code of the entity. In the ribbon workbench set a
* CRM parameter with value PrimaryEntityTypeCode. ex: 1063
*
* @param  templateid: the id for the template you want to download. I had to go to 
* the database to find this and pass it as a string parameter in the ribbon workbench.
* For example: 
* SELECT DocumentTemplateId, Name FROM dbo.DocumentTemplateBase WHERE Name Like '%Quote%';
* returns something like 4AB391A4-D247-E711-80D3-005056914EA2
* Unforunatly, anytime the template is updated, you'll probably have to get the new id.
*
* @param templatetype: the code for the template type. Pass this value in the ribbon 
* workbench as a int param. ex: 9940 is a documenttemplate
* 
* @param filename: the resulting name of the file that will be downloaded to the users 
* computer. Pass this value in the ribbon workbench as a string param. ex: Quote.docx
*
*/
function DownloadTemplate(entitytypecode, templateid, templatetype, filename){
    
    // retrieve the entity id from the current page
    var entityid = new Array();
    entityid.push(Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId());
    
    // try and make a request for the document template
    try{
        
        // clear the page of any previous errors
        Xrm.Page.ui.clearFormNotification("docerror");
        
        // the path that will be used to retrieve the word template
        var funcpath = Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/_grid/print/print_data.aspx";
        
        // open the request to create the template
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open("POST", funcpath, true);
        req.responseType = "arraybuffer";
        req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8");
        req.setRequestHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
        req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        
        // on completion, run the bellow function
        req.onreadystatechange = function () {
            // request complete
            if (this.readyState == 4) {
                req.onreadystatechange = null;
                 // check if we got back a 200 from the request
            if (this.status >= 200 && this.status <= 299) {
                
                // add the download url to an a tag and then click the a tag 
                // to download the document
                var mimetype = (2 === 2) ? "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" : "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                var blob = new Blob([req.response], { type: mimetype });
                var dloadurl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                var a = document.createElement("a");
                
                // if ie, because ie sucks
                if (navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
                    navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, filename);
                    
                // else a browser that doesn't suck
                } else {
                    document.body.appendChild(a);
                    a.style = "display: none";
                    a.href = dloadurl;
                    a.download = filename;
                    a.click();
                    URL.revokeObjectURL(dloadurl);
                }
                
            }
        };
        
        // compile the data to send with the request
        var formdata = "exportType=MergeWordTemplate&selectedRecords=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(entityid)) +
        "&associatedentitytypecode=" + entitytypecode + "&TemplateId=" + templateid + "&templatetype=" + templatetype;
        
        // make the request to create the template
        req.send(formdata);
        
    }catch (err) {
        PrintError(err.message);
    }
}

/*
* PrintError() is a helper method to display any errors to the user.
*/
function PrintError(msg){
    Xrm.Page.ui.setFormNotification("An Error occurred generating the word document, please contact support if the issue persists. " + msg, "ERROR", "docerror");
}
```

IE fix: [.click() giving access denied in IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46232980/click-giving-access-denied-in-ie11)

3. Create a command using XRMToolBox Ribbon Workbench 2016 with the following parameters to execute the JS when the button is clicked.
   [image: Download command]

Comment: a.click();
On Internet explorer is throwing access denied error, but when running from Chrome, Filed is being downloaded but it says "The file is corrupt and cannot be opened".
Any Idea how to deal with these 2 issues.

Comment: @AnkUser I am also having both issues happening to me now. I will investigate and hopefully have a solution to the new problems within the next week.

Comment: @AnkUser for the first problem, check to make sure your Quote ID from the database is correct. If it says the file is corrupt and you open the .doc file from a text editor you'll notice it's an html file. For the IE issue, take a look at my updated code. I added an if statement to run some special code for IE.

Comment: Thanks it helped. Sorry for late reply.

Answer (score 0):

With the new version of CRM this javascript code, need to be amened to remove the unsupported API, as well some addtional changes to be able to work also with CHROME.

below my working version,

```
/*
 * Author:      Matthew Hunt
 * Changes:     Philippe Guarino
 * File:        vsi_DownloadTemplate.js
 * Date:        22/09/2021
 * Project:     CRM USA
 * Description: DownloadTemplate() allows the user to download a document template
 * via a button on the ribbon.
 *
 * @param entitytypecode: the type code of the entity. In the ribbon workbench set a
 * CRM parameter with value PrimaryEntityTypeCode. ex: 1063
 *
 * @param  templateid: the id for the template you want to download. I had to go to
 * the database to find this and pass it as a string parameter in the ribbon workbench.
 * For example:
 * SELECT DocumentTemplateId, Name FROM dbo.DocumentTemplateBase WHERE Name Like '%Quote%';
 * returns something like 4AB391A4-D247-E711-80D3-005056914EA2
 * Unforunatly, anytime the template is updated, you'll probably have to get the new id.
 *
 * @param templatetype: the code for the template type. Pass this value in the ribbon
 * workbench as a int param. ex: 9940 is a documenttemplate
 *
 * @param filename: the resulting name of the file that will be downloaded to the users
 * computer. Pass this value in the ribbon workbench as a string param. ex: Quote.docx
 *
 */

function DownloadTemplate(entitytypecode, templateid, templatetype, filename, formContext)
{
//  var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext(); // get formContext
    // retrieve the entity id from the current page
    var entityid = new Array();
    entityid.push(formContext.data.entity.getId());
    // try and make a request for the document template
    try
    {
        // clear the page of any previous errors
        formContext.ui.clearFormNotification("docerror");
        // the path that will be used to retrieve the word template
        var globalContext = Xrm.Utility.getGlobalContext();
        var funcpath = globalContext.getClientUrl() + "/_grid/print/print_data.aspx";;
        // open the request to create the template
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open("POST", funcpath, true);
        req.responseType = "arraybuffer";
        req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8");
        req.setRequestHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
        req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        // on completion, run the bellow function
        req.onreadystatechange = function ()
        {
            // request complete
            if (this.readyState == 4)
            {
                req.onreadystatechange = null;
                // check if we got back a 200 from the request
                if (this.status >= 200 && this.status <= 299)
                {
                    // add the download url to an a tag and then click the a tag 
                    // to download the document
                    var mimetype = (2 === 2) ? "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" : "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                        var blob = new Blob([req.response],
                    {
                        type: mimetype
                    });
                    

                    
                    var dloadurl = (window.URL ? URL : webkitURL).createObjectURL(blob);
                    var a = document.createElement("a");
                    // if ie, because ie sucks
                    if (navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob)
                    {
                        navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, filename);
                        // else a browser that doesn't suck
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        document.body.appendChild(a);
                        a.style = "display: none";
                        a.href = dloadurl;
                        a.download = filename;
                        a.click();
                        URL.revokeObjectURL(dloadurl);
                    }                
                }
            }
        };
        
    // compile the data to send with the request
            var formdata = "exportType=MergeWordTemplate&selectedRecords=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(entityid)) +
                "&associatedentitytypecode=" + entitytypecode + "&TemplateId=" + templateid + "&templatetype=" + templatetype;
            // make the request to create the template
            req.send(formdata);
            
    }
    catch (err)
    {
        PrintError(err.message);
    }
}
/*
 * PrintError() is a helper method to display any errors to the user.
 */

function PrintError(msg)
{
      Xrm.Page.ui.setFormNotification("An Error occurred generating the word document, please contact support if the issue persists. " + msg, "ERROR", "docerror");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For everyone who wants to generate word documents from JS in Dyn365 Online;

In the internet you can find 'list of undocumented SDK messages' for Dynamics ([CLICK](https://bettercrm.blog/2017/08/02/list-of-undocumented-sdk-messages/)). It is unsupported, but it works now.

> because of their internal nature, they can become obsolete in future releases of CRM without any notice from Microsoft

Thanks to that I prepare a sample code for downloading Word templates (you only need to put that in function, change parameters like EntityTypeCode, templateid, filename... etc.)

```js
fetch(Xrm.Utility.getGlobalContext().getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v9.0/ExportWordDocument", {
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify({
    EntityTypeCode: 1084, //change to valid code
    SelectedRecords: "[\"{6F7651A2-1AE4-ED11-A7C7-000D3ABE768E}\"]", //array of records
    SelectedTemplate: {
        '@odata.type': "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.documenttemplate",
        documenttemplateid: "296cb76d-0b59-e811-8126-5065f38bd3c1" //change to valie templateId or retrieve id by template name earlier
    }
  }),
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Accept-Language": "*"
  }
}).then((response) => response.json())
  .then((json) => {
        const binaryString = window.atob(json.WordFile);
        const bytes = new Uint8Array(binaryString.length);
        const arrayBuffer = bytes.map((byte, i) => binaryString.charCodeAt(i));
        
        const blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer]);
        const fileName = 'TEST.docx';
        if (navigator.msSaveBlob) {
            // IE 10+
            navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName);
        } else {
            const link = document.createElement('a');
            // Browsers that support HTML5 download attribute
            if (link.download !== undefined) {
                const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                link.setAttribute('href', url);
                link.setAttribute('download', fileName);
                link.style.visibility = 'hidden';
                document.body.appendChild(link);
                link.click();
                document.body.removeChild(link);
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score -1):

To get the entity code, run below query:

```
SELECT coalesce(OriginalLocalizedName,name) AS DisplayName, Name AS SchemaName, ObjectTypeCode
FROM EntityLogicalView
ORDER BY ObjectTypeCode
```

and for `Template ID`:

```
SELECT DocumentTemplateId, Name FROM dbo.DocumentTemplateBase
```

Comment: This answer does absolutely nothing to answer the question